# php version 7.1 clean urls

Tags: php, clean-urls

i have an index.php exactly like this

```
echo "<h2>index page</h2>";
$url=explode("/",$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($url);
print_r($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
echo "</pre>";
```

and another one, in the same folder, profile.php with the same code

```
echo "<h2>profile page</h2>";
$url=explode("/",$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($url);
print_r($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
echo "</pre>";
```

i'm trying to build an very simple route system with clean url's.
When the url is like this http://localhost/vas/aaa/bbb
i get from index.php the following result, which is OK:

**index page**
Array
(
    [0] => aaa
    [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CQZn.png) => bbb
)
aaa/bbb

[*printscreen image of index*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CQZn.png)

but, when i type this: http://localhost/vas/profile/john/21, i include the profile in url as a first part of the url i get this:

**profile page**
Array
(
    [0] => 
)

[*printscreen image of profile*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2wr8.png)

That means that wihtout me doing any kind of routing, RUNS the profile.php and the result is an empty url-array without -the MOST important- the expected parameters e.g. john/21.
Why is that, is routing, as functionality, embedded in php 7.* ?
this is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: if you ask for mod_rewrite its Apache problem, its nothing to do with php any version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some explanations of your current .htaccess:

The first 2 lines set up the condition for the url rewrite, in your case it will be rewritten if the specified folder or file in the url is not found:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Then the rewrite rule specifies that the url that was passed should be transmitted to `index.php` as a query string:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

So if you don't have other .htaccess rules, when you call this url `http://localhost/vas/profile/john/21`, you're not supposed to end up in `profile.php` because you don't specify the file name in the url. You should end up in `index.php` with your url as parameter.

However, if the folders `vas/profile/john/21/` actually exist and there's a index.php in it, this is the file that will be called, but because the rewrite won't apply, you will not have your query string.

There's probably something else happening here, other .htacces rules that redirect `/profile/` to `profile.php` or what, that explains you arrive correctly to this file. Extra info could be useful..

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you use **parse_url()** function and the way to route all request to **index.php** in apache

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```